# BOOST_PP_ITERATE() result in "no such file or directory"

Tags: c++, boost, boost-preprocessor

I'm learning the boost preprocessor library (because i need to use it), and I wanted to try the file iteration mechanism. I've set up a minimal project with a.cpp and b.hpp. What I'm trying to do is including many time b.hpp via the boost pp :

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/iteration/iterate.hpp>

#define BOOST_PP_ITERATION_LIMITS (0, 5)
#define BOOST_PP_FILENAME_1 "b.hpp"
#include BOOST_PP_ITERATE()
```

When I try to compile (with -E to see the preprocessor result) :

```
g++ -E a.cpp > pp_result
```

I got this error :

> In file included from a.cpp:
>   /usr/local/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:47:37: error: b.hpp: No such file or directory

b.hpp is in the same directory, I can't see what I'm dooing wrong. It seems the g++ searches b.hpp in the same directory as forward1.hpp, but following the boost documentation my code should work (my boost version is 1.44).

Does anybody experienced the same problem ?

Comment: Does a simple `#include "b.hpp"` work?

Comment: Yes it does. I found a workaroud, using -L./ in the g++ command, but this is still strange since the file is included with "" and not < >.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you need to add `-I.` to the command line in order to make it work. This adds the directory you started gcc in to the include search path, allowing the compiler to find the file `b.hpp`.